# Ввести натуральное число и определить, верно ли, что сумма его цифр равна 10

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int val;
        int summ = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Введите число >= 0");
            val = s.nextInt();
            if (val < 0 || val == 0) {
                System.out.println("Нужно положительное число");
            }
            for (; val > 0; val /= 10) {
                summ += val % 10;
            }
            if (summ != 10) {
                System.out.println("Нет");
            }
        }
        while (summ != 10);
        System.out.println("Да");
    }
    }


Помогите пожалуйста, не могу понять в чем ошибка и как ее решить. Все 
работает до того момента пока не ввожу число > 0, после чего программа 
останавливается
```

Comment: @u_mulder это конструкция do while.

Comment: Ваша программа работает при положительных значениях

Comment: У меня цикл будет длиться до тех пор пока summ не будет равен 10

Comment: Вся логика, от и до неправильная. Во первых тебе нужна проверка, если число однозначное, то смысла нет выполнять программу. Во вторых почему проверка != 10. Не могу понять, что это? Сейчас покажу как сделать.

Comment: @АнтонСарапий Так вы указали, что цикл должен выполняться пока summ не будет равно 10

Comment: Ваша ошибка в том, что вы не сбрасываете в 0 сумму на каждой новой итерации цикла. После строчки val = s.nextInt(); обнулите сумму summ = 0;
Все остальное правильно.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int val;
        int summ;
        do {
            System.out.println("Введите число >= 0");
            val = s.nextInt();
            summ = 0;
            if (val < 0 || val == 0) {
                System.out.println("Нужно положительное число");
            }
            for (; val > 0; val /= 10) {
                summ += val % 10;
            }
            if (summ != 10) {
                System.out.println("Нет");
            }
            if (summ == 10) {
                System.out.println("Да");
                break;
            }
        }
        while (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Опишите, что поменяли и почему.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю вы продолжаете цикл до тех пор пока сумма не будет равна 10, после чего прерываете цикл,

Comment: Если неправильно понял можете поправить, хочу понять что к чему

Comment: да, убрать break; и можно продолжить цикл

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int sumDigits = 0;
        int number;

        do {
            number = scanner.nextInt();
            for (int i = number; number != 0; number /= 10) {
            sumDigits += (number % 10);
        }
        System.out.println(sumDigits + " ");
    }while (number != 0);}}
```